# Will XLWT work in linux platform?

Tags: python, linux, excel

I am working on a project which is based on python windows version. Now the customer wants the project to be extended to linux platform also.

My project uses the package xlwt, xlrd for writing the results to the excel sheet.

So here, Will these packages are compatible with the linux platform also?

Can I use this package in Linux? Or Is there any equivalent package for Linux to write the result to a spreadsheet?

Since my code is very huge,Is there any tool to convert the whole code from windows platform to linux platform?

Comment: Unless these packages don't use Excel API directly they should work. Please consult documentation of these packages for any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, xlrd/xlwt work fine on Linux. Most python code and libraries run the same on any platform.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I have one more query. My project includes a windows based pyd. Can I use that pyd in the linux platform. If not how should I proceed further?

Comment: pyd files are Windows DLLs, not python code, so won't work on Linux.

Comment: On Linux, they're not DLLs. You should start by reading http://docs.python.org/3/extending/ if you're using Python 3, or http://docs.python.org/2/extending/ if you're using Python 2. This will be a question of recompiling (and probably porting) the C or C++ code for the DLL to Linux.